# Problem: Shortest path in a grid between multiple point with a constraint

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search, shortest-path

Problem description:

[image]

I'm trying to solve a problem on the internet and I wasn't able to pass all testcases, well, because my logic is flawed and incorrect. The flaw: I assumed starting to the closest 'F' point will get me to the shortest paths always, at all cases.

Thinks I thought of:

- Turning this into a graph problem and solve it based on it. > don't think this would work because of the constraint?
- Try to obtain all possible solution combinations > does not scale, if !8 combination exist.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility> 
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

#define N 4
#define M 4

int SearchingChallenge(string strArr[], int arrLength) {
  int  n = arrLength, m = n, steps = 0, food = 0;
  // initial position of charlie
  int init_j = 0;
  int init_i = 0;
  queue<pair<int,int>> q;
  // directions
  vector<int> offsets = {0,-1,0,1,0};
  vector<pair<int,int>> food_nodes;
  //store visited nodes, no need for extra work to be done.
  int visited_nodes[4][4] = {{0}};
  
  // get number of food pieces 
  for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < n ; j++){
      if(strArr[i][j] == 'F')
      {
          food++;
      }
      if(strArr[i][j] == 'C')
      {
        strArr[i][j] = 'O';
        food_nodes.push_back({i,j});
      }
    }
  }
  while(food_nodes.size()>0){
      food_nodes.erase(food_nodes.begin());
      int break_flag=0;
      q.push(food_nodes[0]);
  while(!q.empty()){
      int size = q.size();
      while(size-->0){
      pair<int,int> p = q.front();
      q.pop();
      for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
      int ii = p.first + offsets[k], jj = p.second + offsets[k+1];
    /*  if(ii == 0 && jj == 3)
        printf("HI"); */
      if(jj >= 0 && jj < 4 && ii < 4 && ii >=0){
          if(strArr[ii][jj] == 'F'){
             strArr[ii][jj] = 'O';
            while(!q.empty())
                q.pop();
            break_flag=1;
            food--;
            food_nodes.push_back({ii,jj});
            break;
          }
          if(strArr[ii][jj] == 'O')
            q.push({ii,jj});
            
            
            if(strArr[ii][jj] == 'H' && food == 0)
                return ++steps;
        }   
     }
    if(break_flag==1)
        break;
    }
    steps++;
    if(break_flag==1)
        break;
  }
}
  return 0;
}

int main(void) { 
   
  // keep this function call here
  /* Note: In C++ you first have to initialize an array and set 
     it equal to the stdin to test your code with arrays. */

  //passing testcase
  //string A[4] = {"OOOO", "OOFF", "OCHO", "OFOO"};
  //failing testcase
  string A[4] = {"FOOF", "OCOO", "OOOH", "FOOO"}
  int arrLength = sizeof(A) / sizeof(*A);
  cout << SearchingChallenge(A, arrLength);
  return 0;
    
}
```

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: You have a variant of the [manhattan TSP problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). There's no known efficient solution for large graphs, but your problem is small enough that it can be solved by a bitmask DP or even just brute forcing all possible orders for eating the food.

Comment: the order is too big.. I will think of a DP solution. Thanks. i think it is factorial of 8 since F is between 1 and 8.

Comment: 8! = 40320 is a small number when you consider that modern computers can do billions of operations per second. You should be able to loop through every possible permutation in a few milliseconds.

Comment: @bessie, still that would be inelegant. Especially since this problem smell strongly like an interview question. (Nvm, saw your earlier comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a DP solution where you have a 4x4x8 grid. The first two axis represent the x and y coordinate. The third one represent the binary encoding of which food item you picked already.

Each cell in the grid stores the best number of moves to get at this cell having eaten the specified foods. So for example, grid[2][2][2] is the cost of getting to cell (2,2) after having eaten the second piece of food only.

Then you set the value of the start cell, at third index 0 to 0, all the other cells to -1. You keep a list of the cells to propagate (sorted by least cost), and you add the start cell to it.

Then you repeatedly take the next cell to propagate, remove it and push the neighboring cell with cost +1 and updated food consume. Once you reach the destination cell with all food consumed, you're done.

That should take no more than 4x4x8 updates, with about the same order of priority queue insertion. O(n log(n)) where n is x*y*2^f. As long as you have few food items this will be almost instant.

Answer (score 4):

I have wrote the javascript solution for the mentioned problem..

```js
function SearchingChallenge(strArr) {

  // create coordinate array 
  const matrix = [
    [0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3],
    [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3],
    [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3],
    [3, 0], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]
  ]
  // flatten the strArr
  const flattenArray = flatten(strArr)
  // segreagate and map flattenArray with matrix to get coordinate of food,charlie and home 
  const segregatedCoordinates = flattenArray.reduce((obj, char, index) => {
    if (char === 'F') obj['food'].push(matrix[index])
    else if (char === 'C') obj['dog'] = matrix[index]
    else if (char === 'H') obj['home'] = matrix[index]
    return obj
  }, { "food": [], dog: null, home: null })

  // construct possible routes by permutating food coordinates
  let possibleRoutes = permuate(segregatedCoordinates['food'])
  // push dog and home in possibleRoutes at start and end positions
  possibleRoutes = possibleRoutes.map((route) => {
    return [segregatedCoordinates['dog'], ...route, segregatedCoordinates['home']]
  })
  // Calculate distances from every possible route 
  const distances = possibleRoutes.reduce((distances, route) => {
    let moveLength = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < route.length - 1; i++) {
      let current = route[i], next = route[i + 1]
      let xCoordinatePath = current[0] > next[0] ? (current[0] - next[0]) : (next[0] - current[0])
      let yCoordinatePath = current[1] > next[1] ? (current[1] - next[1]) : (next[1] - current[1])
      moveLength += xCoordinatePath + yCoordinatePath
    }
    distances.push(moveLength)
    return distances
  }, [])

  return Math.min(...distances);
}

function permuate(arr) {
  if (arr.length <= 2) return (arr.length === 2 ? [arr, [arr[1], arr[0]]] : arr)
  return arr.reduce((res, ele, index) => {
    res = [...res, ...permuate([...arr.slice(0, index), ...arr.slice(index + 1)]).map(val => [ele, ...val])]
    return res
  }, [])
}


function flatten(inputtedArr) {
  return inputtedArr.reduce((arr, row) => {
    arr = [...arr, ...row]
    return arr
  }, [])
}

console.log(SearchingChallenge(['FOOF', 'OCOO', 'OOOH', 'FOOO']));
```

Comment: This is the cleanest and accurate code a person can produce.

Answer (score 0):

C++ solution
I used both dfs and bfs for this problem
**TIME COMPLEXITY** - (4^(N×M))+NO_OF_FOODS×N×M

```cpp
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

//It is a dfs function it will find and store all the possible steps to eat all food in toHome map
void distAfterEatingAllFood(vector<vector<char>> &m, int countOfFood, int i, int j, int steps, map<pair<int,int>,int>&toHome){
    if(i<0 || j<0 || i>=4 || j>=4 || m[i][j]=='*') return;
    if(m[i][j]=='F') countOfFood--;
    if(countOfFood==0){
        if(!toHome.count({i,j}))
            toHome[{i,j}] = steps;
        else if(toHome[{i,j}]>steps)
            toHome[{i,j}] = steps;
        return;
    }
    char temp = m[i][j];
    m[i][j] = '*';
    distAfterEatingAllFood(m, countOfFood, i+1, j, steps+1, toHome);
    distAfterEatingAllFood(m, countOfFood, i-1, j, steps+1, toHome);
    distAfterEatingAllFood(m, countOfFood, i, j+1, steps+1, toHome);
    distAfterEatingAllFood(m, countOfFood, i, j-1, steps+1, toHome);
    m[i][j] = temp;
    return;
    
}
//It is a bfs function it will iterate over the toHome map and find the shortest distance between the last food position to home
int lastFoodToHome(vector<vector<char>> &m, int i, int j, int steps){
    queue<pair<pair<int, int>,int>>q;
    vector<vector<int>> vis(4, vector<int>(4, 0));
    q.push({{i, j}, steps});
    vis[i][j] = 1;
    int dirX[] = {0, 1, 0, -1};
    int dirY[] = {1, 0, -1, 0};
    while (!q.empty())
    {
        int x = q.front().first.first;
        int y = q.front().first.second;
        int steps = q.front().second;
        q.pop();
        if (m[x][y] == 'H')
            return steps;
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++)
        {
            int ni = x + dirX[k];
            int nj = y + dirY[k];
            if (ni >= 0 && nj >= 0 && ni < 4 && nj < 4 && !vis[ni][nj])
            {
                if(m[ni][nj] == 'H') return steps + 1; 
                q.push({{ni, nj}, steps + 1});
                vis[i][j] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return INT_MAX;
}
int main()
{
    vector<vector<char>> m(4, vector<char>(4));
    int countOfFood = 0, x, y;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            cin >> m[i][j];
            if (m[i][j] == 'C'){
                x = i;
                y = j;
            }
            if (m[i][j] == 'F')
                countOfFood++;
        }
    }
    map<pair<int,int>,int>toHome;
    distAfterEatingAllFood(m, countOfFood, x, y, 0, toHome);
    int ans = INT_MAX;
    for(auto &i:toHome){
        ans = min(ans, lastFoodToHome(m, i.first.first, i.first.second, i.second));
    }
    cout<<ans;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it.